# Angular2 currency pipe EUR format

Tags: angular, pipe, currency, angular2-pipe

I already tried to use `<span>{{(price | currency: 'EUR': true)}}</span>`
and `{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: "de-DE" }`. However, server environment is based in USA and I can't change language location there.

Then the standard format is **$1,000.00**, but I need this format **1.000,00 €**

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this (a little bit tricky) :

Declare your custom pipe, it will replace ',' buy '.' and '.' by ',' :

```
@Pipe({ name: 'customPipe' })
export class ToCustomPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: string):any {
        if(value == null) return '';
        value = value.toString().replace(/,/, "*");
        value = value.toString().replace(/./, ",");
        value = value.toString().replace(/*/, ".");
        return value;
    }
}
```

then in your html :

```
<span>{{(price | currency:'USD':false | customPipe)}} €</span>
```

Comment: showing error in line  value = value.toString().replace(/*/, ".");